# Next lint not working on files anywhere other than the ones inside the pages folder

Tags: next.js, eslint

I have a FRESHLY installed NextJS app with TypeScript. I am using Next V12, when I run `yarn lint`, it runs `next lint` and shows no errors.

[image: No errors whatsoever]

And now when I add an extra rule in the `.eslintrc` file like `"no-unused-vars": 2` (it means to show an error when there's an un-used variable), and add an un-used variable on purpose in my `index.tsx` file inside the `pages` folder so that I can test the linting, it works as expected.

[image: Linting works in pages folder]

But when I add another folder called `hooks` and add an `index.tsx` file with unused variables in it, it doesn't capture the unused variable error in hooks folder, only captures the ones inside `pages` folder.

My `.eslintrc` file looks like this -

```
{
    "extends": "next/core-web-vitals",
    "rules": {
        "no-unused-vars": 2
    }
}
```

If anyone faced this issue before and knows what I'm doing wrong, please suggest.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/cli#lint), `next lint` runs ESLint for files in the following folders: `pages`, `components`, and `lib`.

To run ESLint for other folders as well, you have to use the  `--dir` flag.

You can either do so directly in the terminal:

```
yarn run lint -- --dir . //for all folders in your project root directory

yarn run lint -- --dir pages hooks //only for the folders "pages" and "hooks"
```

Or change the `lint` script in `package.json`:

```json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "lint": "next lint --dir ." //or "next lint --dir pages hooks"
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Note that the above is for development mode.

For [production mode](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#linting-custom-directories-and-files), you can add the `dirs` option to `eslint` in `next.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  eslint: {
    dirs: ['.'] //or ['pages', 'hooks']
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I should've gone through the docs, could've saved so much time.

Answer (score 1):

In nextjs 13, and if you're working with the 'src' folder, you can just add this folder to your eslint directory like the following:

```js
// next.config.js
const nextConfig = {
  ..., // other config
  eslint: {
    dirs: ["src"],
  },
};
```

Comment: It seems like it should work, but still doesn't work for me