# Failed to load config "next/babel" to extend from eslintrc.json

Tags: next.js, babeljs, eslint, vercel, eslintrc

When I'm trying to build the Next.Js app then the below error is coming with a successful build. This error is showing when I deploy the app in Vercel.

```
error - ESLint: Failed to load config "next/babel" to extend from. Referenced from: /vercel/path0/.eslintrc.json
```

This is my **.eslintrc.json**

```
{
  "extends": ["next/babel","next/core-web-vitals"]
}
```

I've also added **.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": []
}
```

I also found a solution when I change the **eslintrc.json** file like below:

```
{
  "extends": ["next","next/core-web-vitals"]
}
```

then no error is showing while building the app. But there is another problem showing when I use the above solution and the problem is:

```
Parsing error: Cannot find module 'next/babel'
```

This is shown in all the imports with red marks.

I tried to search the solution but did not found any solution for this.

Comment: what's your package.json ?

Comment: I have this exact same issue. Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 40):

I think, this might have to do with this weird hackfix that is being touted in a bunch of places that tells you to place `next/babel` in your `eslint` config file for some reason (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68193974)).

It probably was a hackfix for an old bug in older next.js versions. But as of (at least) summer 2022, it makes little sense to do so, considering that [`next/babel`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/customizing-babel-config) is a babel preset, not an eslint preset. Instead, in recent next.js versions, just reset your `.eslintrc.json`:

```json
{
  "extends": [
    "next"
  ]
}
```

With this setup, things don't error out, as of `next@12.2.*`.

You also might want to take a look next's [`eslint` customization options](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint). For example, some people might be confused why `eslint` is seemingly not working.
In that case, consider [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71284119) and [the next.js docs on `eslint`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#linting-custom-directories-and-files).

If you have this problem, but you did not copy+paste your `.eslintrc.json` from the interwebz, then you might need to describe your situation in more detail.

Comment: I replaced this `"next/babel"` with `"next"` under `extends` array in .eslintrc.json (placed in root), fixed the linting issue, `ESLint: Failed to load config "next/babel" to extend from.`

Answer (score 7):

Same Turborepo issue using pnpm. This solved it for me: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/40687#issuecomment-1275184829

Essentially add this to your settings.json

```
// .vscode/settings.json

{
  "eslint.workingDirectories": [
    { "pattern": "apps/*/" },
    { "pattern": "packages/*/" }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Or just replace `"next"` and `"next/core-web-vitals"` to
`"plugin:@next/next/recommended"`

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint

Answer (score 5):

my problem has been solved by this code. just copy and paste it into the eslintrc.json file.

```
{
  "extends": ["next/babel","next/core-web-vitals"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue when working with TurboRepo's `with-tailwind` example.

Somehow ESlint was working just fine, but this error occurred. I solved it by adding `next` as a dev-dependency to `eslint-custom-config` to the package:

```
pnpm install next@latest -D
```

```json
{
  "name": "eslint-config-custom",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "next": "^13.2.4"
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "public"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when working with TurboRepo. The solution for me was to add `next` as a `devDependency` in the root of the monorepo.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when my project was not at the root of the repo, alongside other type issues coming from typescript. Moving everything to the root level have resolved it.